# Pig script output of charrarry column comes out as exponent number

Tags: hadoop, casting, apache-pig

I have been working on a Pig script that reads a file, does some transformations, and spits out a file. In my input file, I have my identity column - lets say `ID` - that has value of `6461393E3`.

I am loading the file something like this

```
a = load '/Myfile.txt' as (id:chararry, ....);
b = load 'myfile2.txt' as (id:chararry, name:chararray);
c = join a by (id) left outer, b by (id);
d = foreach c generate a::id, b::name;
```

When I save the file post transformations, I am getting output that looks like this

`6.46E+09`

Does anyone know what is the reason behind this and how can I avoid that?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the transformations?

Comment: Looks weird, can you post some input data.

Comment: Are you reading this in Excel? Are you certain that is how pig is out putting the info or just how it is being displayed to you? That looks like scientific notation, which Excel will do with large numbers. It may simply be an issue with your viewer of choice. Try a text editor?

Comment: Dump whatever relation you're saving, see what it looks like there.